# Renaming XML elements using value of attributes at nested level

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I have a xml document having nested level `<div>` element with attribute.
I want to rename div by attribute name.

Comment: Please provide a specific example of what you're trying to achieve - e.g. an excerpt from the source XML file and the desired output for that excerpt.

Comment: Accept the answer that helped you with the checkmark icon under the vote counts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="div">
  <xsl:element name="{@class}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the following XML document**:

```
<html>
  <div class="animal">
     Animals:
     <div class="mammal">
       Mammals:
        <div class="dog">
          Dogs
        </div>
        <div class="cat">Cats</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</html>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<html>
   <animal class="animal">
      Animals:

      <mammal class="mammal">
         Mammals:

         <dog class="dog">
                      Dogs

         </dog>
         <cat class="cat">Cats</cat>
      </mammal>
   </animal>
</html>
```

**Explanation**:

Proper use of the **[identity rule](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)** design pattern.

Comment: This renames the `<div>` element to the value of the `class` attribute. The requirement was to "rename div by attribute name".

Comment: @Borodin You seem to be very quick to downvote! I thought that the OP meant *generically* any attribute. So I chose just one attribute that may be present on a `class` element. I think an HTML `div` element doesn't have a `name` attribute.

Comment: I haven't downvoted you. And I understand "attribute name" to mean "name of the attribute". The OP needs to clarify

Comment: @Borodin: Agreed that OP's clarification is necessary. Till then this answer at least gives an idea how this kind of tasks can be solved.